# undeclared identifier for user created class object instantiation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, inheritance

So I'm working on creating a cube made out of rectangles made out lines made out of points. I did the one thing you are never supposed to do, write the entire thing before the first run. what follows is a stripped down version for the purpose of spotting the first error.

this is in visual studio, so this may be strictly a visual studio problem. I'm not sure. I haven't tested it in fedora to verify.

here is Point_class.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class PointType
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
public:
    PointType(int i=0, int j=0, int k=0);
    void get_point(int& i, int &j, int& k) const;
    void set_point(int i, int j, int k);
};


#endif /* POINT_H */
```

here's Point_class.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Point_class.h"

PointType::PointType(int i, int j, int k)
{
    x = i;
    y = j;
    z = k;
}

void PointType::get_point(int& i, int &j, int& k) const 
{
    i = x;
    j = y;
    k = z;
}

void PointType::set_point(int i, int j, int k)
{
    x = i;
    y = j;
    z = k;
}
```

here is the main cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point_class.h"
#include "stdafx.h"


int main()
{
    PointType p1;
    PointType p2(8, 0, 0);
    PointType p3(0, 9, 0);
    PointType p4(0, 0, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

the first error I get is C2065 undeclared identifier at line 10 in the main program, and the second is error 2146 (expected ';' before identifier p1) on the same line. all the other errors are just repeats of that one.

both the header and the cpp file for point class have been added to the source files. I'm not sure how compiling works in visual studio(I think it's done automatically once the source files are added. I know if I was using the terminal i would just have to specify those files when using g++. Any pointers would be helpful.

EDIT: deleted "#include "stdafx.h"" out of header file. reran just to be sure but no change.

Comment: please show the complete error. PLease show which file it is complaining about. Please indicate the line its complaining about

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` if you are using [precompiled headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca.aspx) then you must include them first in the cpp files only

Comment: Also `pointclass.h` is not the same with `Point_class.h` in main file `#include "Point_class.h"`

Comment: that last one was a typo, just fixed it. I checked to make sure but the files are properly named.

Comment: I wonder if point_h is already defined. Since you have 'pragma once' just take the include guard out

Answer (score 0):

So I found the source of the error. I noticed one error that was different in the error list at the end pointing to the point_class implementation file saying something about reached end of file. so I added #include "stdafx.h" to the end of the list of includes. This caused a series of new errors, which promptly went away when I changed the location of the include to the first line, along with the original error. This prompted me to try to put #include "stdafx.h" at the beginning of the main file, which resulted in a properly running program.

Thanks Raxvan, you kind of gave me the idea to try to move that line around.